# Masstransit how to add activity

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I have created service with RabbitMq bus.
Now, I'm trying to add activity to that bus (I tried every registration option I found)

```java
    private void ConfigureBus(IServiceCollectionConfigurator configurator)
    {
        configurator.AddActivity(typeof(StepAcitivity));
        configurator.AddActivitiesFromNamespaceContaining<StepAcitivity>();
        configurator.AddActivity<StepAcitivity, StepArguments, StepLog>();
        configurator.AddConsumer<PingConsumer>();
    }
```

I also registered StepAcitivity at container:

```java
    services.AddScoped<StepAcitivity>();
```

From another service:
First: test ping request/response that is worked as expected:

```java
    IRequestClient<IPingRequest, IPingResponse> client =
                   busControl.CreateRequestClient<IPingRequest, IPingResponse>(serviceAddress, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                IPingResponse s = await client.Request(request);
```

Second:
Create and Execute activity

```java
    string address = config.GetValue<string>("executorAddress");
    Uri sendAddress = new Uri($"queue:{address}");
    RoutingSlipBuilder builder = new RoutingSlipBuilder(NewId.NextGuid());
    
    builder.AddActivity("SetepA", sendAddress);
    builder.AddActivity("StepB", sendAddress);
    builder.AddActivity("StepC", sendAddress);
    RoutingSlip routingSlip = builder.Build();
    return routingSlip;
```

Execute:

```java
    await bus.Execute(routingSlip);
```

The problem that ping request/response is working as expected but routingSlip does not fails but I am not getting any call at activity side.
At rabbitMQ management is see that message moved to WorkerService_skipped queue.

1. What am i missing at activity registration at worker service side? (bus looks ok, since i am able to run post IPingRequest request and to read response on same address)
2. If message moved to skipped queue, why call to  `await bus.Execute(routingSlip)` is not falling?
   My masstransit version is : 6.2.3

My worker service probe:

```json
    {
      "resultId": "a4984523-5ffc-4ff4-8ceb-498029dbfeff",
      "probeId": "561351df-42da-44a7-83ce-29a467966663",
      "startTimestamp": "2020-07-06T12:51:32.0106524Z",
      "duration": "00:00:00.0427169",
      "host": {
        "machineName": "SLAVAF-LAP",
        "processName": "WorkerService",
        "processId": 38212,
        "assembly": "WorkerService",
        "assemblyVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "frameworkVersion": "3.1.5",
        "greenPipesVersion": "3.0.1.0",
        "operatingSystemVersion": "Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0"
      },
      "results": {
        "bus": {
          "address": "rabbitmq://localhost:0/SLAVAFLAP_WorkerService_bus_x37yyyd4rz1m1wcfbdcndk4enp?temporary=true",
          "host": {
            "Type": "RabbitMQ",
            "Host": "localhost",
            "Port": 5672,
            "VirtualHost": "/",
            "Username": "slava",
            "Password": "****",
            "Heartbeat": 0,
            "Ssl": false,
            "connected": true,
            "receiveEndpoint": [
              {
                "name": "WorkerService",
                "started": true,
                "transport": {
                  "type": "RabbitMQ",
                  "ExchangeName": "WorkerService",
                  "ExchangeArguments": [],
                  "ExchangeType": "fanout",
                  "Durable": true,
                  "AutoDelete": false,
                  "QueueName": "WorkerService",
                  "Exclusive": false,
                  "QueueArguments": [
                    [
                      "x-queue-type",
                      {}
                    ]
                  ],
                  "BindingArguments": [],
                  "PrefetchCount": 16,
                  "PurgeOnStartup": false,
                  "ExclusiveConsumer": false,
                  "NoAck": false,
                  "BindQueue": true,
                  "ConsumeArguments": [],
                  "topology": {
                    "exchange": [
                      {
                        "Name": "WorkerService",
                        "Type": "fanout",
                        "Durable": true,
                        "AutoDelete": false
                      },
                      {
                        "Name": "Common.Messages.Ping:IPingRequest",
                        "Type": "fanout",
                        "Durable": true,
                        "AutoDelete": false
                      }
                    ],
                    "queue": {
                      "Name": "WorkerService",
                      "Durable": true,
                      "AutoDelete": false,
                      "Exclusive": false,
                      "argument": {
                        "key": "x-queue-type",
                        "value": "quorum"
                      }
                    },
                    "exchange-binding": {
                      "Source": "Common.Messages.Ping:IPingRequest",
                      "Destination": "WorkerService"
                    },
                    "queue-binding": {
                      "Source": "WorkerService",
                      "Destination": "WorkerService"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "filters": [
                  {
                    "filterType": "deadLetter",
                    "filters": {
                      "filterType": "dead-letter"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "filterType": "rescue",
                    "filters": [
                      {
                        "filterType": "generateFault"
                      },
                      {
                        "filterType": "moveFault"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "filterType": "deserialize",
                    "deserializers": {
                      "json": {
                        "contentType": "application/vnd.masstransit+json"
                      },
                      "bson": {
                        "contentType": "application/vnd.masstransit+bson"
                      },
                      "xml": {
                        "contentType": "application/vnd.masstransit+xml"
                      }
                    },
                    "consumePipe": {
                      "filters": {
                        "filterType": "dispatchPipe",
                        "outputType": "MassTransit.ConsumeContext<Common.Messages.Ping.IPingRequest>",
                        "filters": {
                          "filterType": "MessageFilter",
                          "Type": "Common.Messages.Ping.IPingRequest"
                        },
                        "consumer": {
                          "type": "WorkerService.Consumers.PingConsumer",
                          "consumerFactory": {
                            "source": "scope",
                            "consumerType": "WorkerService.Consumers.PingConsumer",
                            "provider": "dependencyInjection"
                          },
                          "filters": {
                            "filterType": "split",
                            "ConsumerType": "WorkerService.Consumers.PingConsumer",
                            "filters": {
                              "filterType": "ScopedLoggingFilter"
                            }
                          },
                          "consume": {
                            "method": "Consume(ConsumeContext<Common.Messages.Ping.IPingRequest> context)"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "name": "SLAVAFLAP_WorkerService_bus_x37yyyd4rz1m1wcfbdcndk4enp",
                "started": true,
                "transport": {
                  "type": "RabbitMQ",
                  "ExchangeName": "SLAVAFLAP_WorkerService_bus_x37yyyd4rz1m1wcfbdcndk4enp",
                  "ExchangeArguments": [],
                  "ExchangeType": "fanout",
                  "Durable": false,
                  "AutoDelete": true,
                  "QueueName": "SLAVAFLAP_WorkerService_bus_x37yyyd4rz1m1wcfbdcndk4enp",
                  "Exclusive": false,
                  "QueueExpiration": "00:01:00",
                  "QueueArguments": [],
                  "BindingArguments": [],
                  "PrefetchCount": 16,
                  "PurgeOnStartup": false,
                  "ExclusiveConsumer": false,
                  "NoAck": false,
                  "BindQueue": true,
                  "ConsumeArguments": [],
                  "topology": {
                    "exchange": {
                      "Name": "SLAVAFLAP_WorkerService_bus_x37yyyd4rz1m1wcfbdcndk4enp",
                      "Type": "fanout",
                      "Durable": false,
                      "AutoDelete": true
                    },
                    "queue": {
                      "Name": "SLAVAFLAP_WorkerService_bus_x37yyyd4rz1m1wcfbdcndk4enp",
                      "Durable": false,
                      "AutoDelete": false,
                      "Exclusive": false,
                      "argument": {
                        "key": "x-expires",
                        "value": 60000
                      }
                    },
                    "queue-binding": {
                      "Source": "SLAVAFLAP_WorkerService_bus_x37yyyd4rz1m1wcfbdcndk4enp",
                      "Destination": "SLAVAFLAP_WorkerService_bus_x37yyyd4rz1m1wcfbdcndk4enp"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "filters": [
                  {
                    "filterType": "deadLetter",
                    "filters": {
                      "filterType": "dead-letter"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "filterType": "rescue",
                    "filters": [
                      {
                        "filterType": "generateFault"
                      },
                      {
                        "filterType": "moveFault"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "filterType": "deserialize",
                    "deserializers": {
                      "json": {
                        "contentType": "application/vnd.masstransit+json"
                      },
                      "bson": {
                        "contentType": "application/vnd.masstransit+bson"
                      },
                      "xml": {
                        "contentType": "application/vnd.masstransit+xml"
                      }
                    },
                    "consumePipe": {}
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Each activity requires a separate endpoint for execution, and if compensation is supported by the activity an additional endpoint for compensation. You cannot configure your activities on the same endpoint, and the endpoints should not be shared with other services.

Using AddActivity() is enough to configure the container, you do not need to call AddScoped with your activity.

Also, you can use ConfigureEndpoints and pass the registration context to configure the bus endpoints for all of the activities, sagas, and consumers.

> The probe you included (which is great, thank you) shows that you only have a single receive endpoint, WorkerService, which has a consumer that handles the `IPingRequest` message.

Comment: Thanks! I suspected that it is endpoints issue. But why routing slip execution does not throws?  Do you have some code example that shows how to connect activity with endpoints?  http://masstransit-project.com/advanced/courier/activities is missing this part . The twitch example is hard to run locally , since it has a lot of dependencies .

Comment: Execute sends to the endpoint, the fact you don't have anything configured on it doesn't affect execute.

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed answer! What about example of activity binding to specific endpoint using Microsoft container? Assuming i want to call to AddActivitiesFromNamespaceContaining, and my namespace contains couple of activities. How do i bind each activity from namespace to specific endpoint? Is that done by some naming convention between activity name and endpoint name?

Comment: Found the answer about how endpoint name is connected to saga/consumer/activity. https://masstransit-project.com/usage/containers/